Language mode of .tsx and .ts in Visual Studio code is "plain text"
I am having a problem with the language mode of some .tsx and .ts files being "plain text" on Visual Studio code.
On my desktop PC, this problem does not occur, but on my laptop, which does not share Visual Studio code settings, the language mode of .tsx and .ts files is plain text, regardless of whether it is on WSL or Windows, and the VScode language modes "TypeScript", and "TypeScript JSX".
This never happened on my laptop to begin with, but one day it suddenly started happening, whether it was related to an update of VScode or not.
In rare cases, the language mode of .tsx and .ts is assigned to the appropriate one even on the laptop in certain workspaces, but this is not reproducible, and even on this workspace, when I open the folder where .tsx exists by “File>Open Folder”, the language mode of .tsx is plain text.
Adding the following code to setting.json of Visual Studio code itself and to .vscode/setting.json directly under the directory where I am developing does not fix the problem, only displaying the react icon next to the file.
{
  "files.associations": {
      "*.tsx": "typescriptreact"
  }
}

I have restarted my PC, restarted Visual Studio code, reinstalled, etc. and it still does not go away.
I don't think it is the extension's fault, as some workspaces do not have this symptom.
